# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'cv'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opencv, cocos2d-iphone

I am using OpenCV framework for image processing, i am identifying edge in photo for
normal iOS project, now i am converting this code in cocos2d project, i have imported all
required headers but while compiling  i am getting this error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'cv'. here is my code

```
     #import "cocos2d.h"
     #import "CameraController.h"
     #import "Globals.h"

     @interface BotoxEffectController : CCLayer 
     { cv::VideoCapture *_videoCapture; cv::Mat _lastFrame;}//this is line where i am
       getting error

     @property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *sprite2D;
     +(CCScene *) scene;
     @end

     here is code in .pch file.

     #import <Availability.h>

     #ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
     #warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
     #endif

     #ifdef __cplusplus
     #import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
     #endif

     #ifdef __OBJC__
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     #endif
```

Please refer below screen shot BotoxEffectController class interface where error is & implementation file has extension .mm.
[image: BotoxEffectController]

here is .pch file where i am importing opencv.hpp

[image: .pch]

Comment: Make sure any file that imports this has the extension .mm, not .m

Comment: yes file has extension .mm

Comment: Isn't OpenCV C code? Is cv supposed to be a C++ namespace? My hunch is that it should be cvVideoCapture and cvMat.

Comment: Ah, OpenCV2 has moved to C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on here. Try adding the OpenCV header to your BotoxEffectController header file:

```
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

If this fixes the compile errors, the problem is with the prefix.pch. For some reason it doesn't parse the `#if __cplusplus` part. You can verify it by adding a warning to it, see if it triggers:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#warning "ok so it DID import the OpenCV header"
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

If that is the issue, I can't tell you why the opencv header in the prefix.pch won't work. I only remember having had this issue once or twice before, but can't remember how I fixed it.  One thing you should check: the BotoxEffectController.h should have its File Type set to "Default - C Header" and not C++ header.

Comment: the OpenCV headers must be included before UIKit.h and Foundation.h because OpenCV defines a MIN macro that conflicts with the MIN function defined by the Apple frameworks. If you include the OpenCV headers after UIKit.h and Foundation.h you will receive compilation errors such as ‘LLVM GCC 4.2 Error: Statement-expressions are allowed only inside functions’. Including the OpenCV headers first and surrounding the #import with the __cplusplus conditional test avoids this problem and means that you can still use plain Objective-C for ‘.m‘ files in your project that don’t call the OpenCV APIs.